# Creation of a ID2D1DCRenderTarget

Tags: c++, windows, hook, direct2d, dll-injection

I'm trying to create a GDI device context from Direct2D but when I call `CreateDCRenderTarget`, it returns `D2DERR_NO_HARDWARE_DEVICE` error and my RenderTarget is null.
Is there something wrong with the properties ?

```
ID2D1Factory* _pDirect2dFactory = NULL;
ID2D1DCRenderTarget *_pRenderTarget = NULL;

D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES props = D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(
    D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT,
    D2D1::PixelFormat(
        DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM,
        D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE),
    0,
    0,
    D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_USAGE_NONE,
    D2D1_FEATURE_LEVEL_DEFAULT
    );

  HRESULT hr;

  hr = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &_pDirect2dFactory);

  if (_pDirect2dFactory)
  {
    // *** ERROR here *** : hr=0x8899000B (D2DERR_NO_HARDWARE_DEVICE)
    hr = _pDirect2dFactory->CreateDCRenderTarget(&props, &_pRenderTarget);
  }
```

**EDIT** :
That code works fine when it is called from my executable but do not work when it is called from another program through my injected DLL.

**EDIT2** :
Well, that works now. This code was called when my DLL was attached and I think that D2D1.dll was not correctly attached to the process yet.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong there - what OS are you running on?

Comment: Do I need to create a device before with `D3D11CreateDevice` ?

Comment: No need for a D3D11 device at all if you're only using D2D - do you have a DX11 capable graphics card?

Comment: Yes, I have a Quadro K5000.

Comment: Well copy/paste of your code works fine on my Win8 64 with Quadro FX580 and VS2012. Have you tried a driver update?

Comment: I've tried my code in a simple program, it works... In fact this code is called in a DLL when I inject it in another process. So yeah, that's not a Direct2D issue.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still had a same problem injecting dll which creates d2d, try putting the function into a new thread. In my case, I put directly the d2d creating function into new thread by CreateThread in DllMain and it works.